# Reselect - does it ever make sense to pass only part of the state to a selector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

My store contains an array of `goal`s. There's a Goal component which I connect to the redux store with connect() so it has a `goal` as its props.

The Goal component has children which all need the whole goal object to create derived data from. I want to use reselect to help extract how this data is derived, but it doesn't make sense to me to select the same goal from the whole redux store again, when I already have access to the goal.

So I'm currently passing in the goal object from the Goal component to its children and calling a selector on it as I do so.

This means the selector's argument is just one goal, a part of the state, rather than all of the state. All examples of how to use this use "connect" so the selector functions take in the whole of the state.

Does my approach make any sense? Or have I completely missed the point and I've no longer properly encapsulated the shape of the state tree?

any comments / advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the selector is to hold derived data so that your redux store doesn't have to. It's legit to pass in sub-pieces of the state tree:

```
const getThing = state => state.the.thing.I.care.about;
const getBoundaryConditions = state => state.the.boundary.conditions.man.whoa;

export const getTheThingICareAbout = createSelector(
  [ getThing, getBoundaryConditions ],
  (thing, conditions) => {
    //do stuff to thing depending on conditions
    return thing.beConditionallyAwesome(conditions);
  }
);
```

Also, while it's possible to pass the goal object down to the children of the Goal component through props, it would be better to pass an id value (or something) down to the children through props and have the children get the corresponding goal from the state tree using `connect()` (see the powerful third `mergeProps` argument of `connect()` [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) which allows you to use passed in props `ownProps` alongside the whole state tree and dispatch - it can be quite handy).

This is better because the Goal component doesn't have to pass a big fat object down through a prop. Instead, the children components can select specific parts of the goal object that they care about in `mapStateToProps()` and keep the component props shallow as they should be.

...at least that's my opinion. Good luck with it!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.
So to clarify - `goalComponent` receives its id from props, then uses a selector and connect to get the goal part of the state. (I already do that part)
But then rather than passing the whole goal down to each `goalChildComponent`, I just pass the id again, and each `goalChildComponent` calls the same function to select the same goal from the state again, and just uses a different function to create the different derived data?

I didn't like the idea of repeatedly grabbing the same part of the state when I could just pass it around. But I think you're right.

Comment: Your suggestion matches what the docs suggest, so I'll go with that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to pass in a goal via props (from parent to child) - this meant the parent is "smart" (knows about the state) and the child if "dumb" (just renders what it is given in props).

Alternatively you can access the state (as much or as little of it as you like) in the child components.